# Combinatorics related math problem...need suggestion

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, permutations, combinations

I am trying to solve the following question:

> In a programming class of $7$ students, the instructor wants each student to modify the program from a previous assignment; however, no student should work on his or her own assignment. In how many ways can the instructor assign programs to the students.

I was trying to solve this with the following thoughts.

Each student among $7$ students have to choose from other $6$ previous assignment excluding his/her own assignment. So, $6$ ways an instructor can assign to one student.
Therefore, $6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1 = 6!$ ways can the instructor assign programs to the students.

Answer: 6!

**Is the solution I am thinking is correct or there is some problem..please let me know**

Comment: No, that's wrong. I am not sure how $6 \cdot 6 \cdot...6$ gives you $6!$. In any case, assignment to eqch student is not independent of others. If you assign student A the program that was B's then B has 6 choices but if you assign C's program to A then B has 5 choices. Please look up derangement in wiki.

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: @user2661923 that was a spelling mistake...I meant 6!..since the choices becoming fewer and fewer as each student has chosen an assignment.

and from your explanation I understand, the answer could be, 6! * 5! * 4! * 3! * 2! * 1!....

Is that what you are saying?

Comment: No.  I am saying that the entire topic of derangements is very complicated and needs to be studied.  This is why I provided the link to the article.

Comment: @user2661923
I get that...article was quite helpful...thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem relates to derangement, if the number of students were 4, then the total number of ways $= \frac{4!}{1- (1/1!) + (1/2!) - (1/3!) + (1/4!)}
                     = 9$
Do the same for 7 students and that will be the answer.